# Not able to save date from datepicker widget into my database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am new in Django. Basically i have a form in which i have a date_of_birth field and i am take imput into it through a datepicker widget. But i am not able to store it into my database(SQLite).
Here's my model.py-:

```
class users(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
dob = models.DateField(max_length=30)
phone = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

here's forms.py-:

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
input_type = 'date'
class user_form(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),required=True,max_length=30)
email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(), required=True, max_length=50)
phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput)

dob = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
class Meta():
    model = users

    fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'dob']
```

here's View.py-:

```
def userdata(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = user_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user-form/')
else:
    form = user_form()
return render(request, 'user_form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: `max_length` is not an attribute of `DateField`. Also class Meta does not need parenthesis: `class Meta:`

Comment: What do you try to accomplish overriding DateInput class?

Comment: corrected all the things you said , still getting the same error. I am able to to submit the form but when i try to look it up from admin panel then it gives typerror - "expected string or bytes-like object"